# How to compile Java 9 and subsequent releases code in JDK8?

Tags: java, cross-compiling, javac, javacompiler, bootclasspath

I have a maven aggregate project that contains `api`, `application`, `domain`, `infrastructure` and `common-util` modules.

The aggregate project JDK version is 17, but the `common-util` module alone uses JDK8 instead of 17 (for more compatibility).

All source code in `common-util` modules does not use Java 9 and subsequent releases' syntax, but this module uses the `JDK HTTP Client` provided since Java 11. The HTTP interface class has two implementation classes, `Java11Impl` and `ApacheImpl`, and the latter should be used for versions lower than Java11.

Now the problem is that I can't compile the module with JDK8, the compiler tells me `package java.net.http does not exist`.

Can I get the compilation done by javac options like `-bootclasspath`? How should I do this?

Comment: Java 8 can compile code written for Java 8 _or lower_ but cannot compile code that uses features of Java 9+ — on the other hand Java 9+ (including Java 11) _can_ compile code written to Java 8 specs. You should be able to use JDK 11-17 to compile _all_ the code, you don't have to switch to an older version to compile the older code.

Comment: @Stephen P: I've avoided using Java 9+ features. I can compile the source code to Java 8 version bytecode (Major version is 52) through JDK 11+, but the module may depend on some dependent jars with a Major version higher than 52 (such as jakarta.ws.rs-api:3.1.0‘ classes version is 55) and maybe I don't know this kind of situation. This meant that my code will happen a fatal error when running on JRE8(unrecognized high Major version classes file), but when I compiled with JDK11+ I wasn't told this was the case, JDK8 seemed to throw an error, so I think it's safer to compile with JDK8.